# Ajax autocomplete not working for search box asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to Create a google like search box.I am not getting any result of this. Am just trying to make the auto complete feature for now the search thing is not yet done .Below is what i have tried.

<====== Directory.aspx file =======>

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager  ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

       <div class="search-box">
           <span class="strong">Search Members: </span> 
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autoComplete1" runat="server"
  EnableCaching="true"
  BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
  MinimumPrefixLength="2"
  TargetControlID="myTextBox"
  ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
  ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
  CompletionInterval="100"  
  CompletionSetCount="20"
  CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
  CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem"
  CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
  DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
  ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
  <Animations>
  <OnShow>
  <Sequence>
  <%-- Make the completion list transparent and then show it --%>
  <OpacityAction Opacity="0" />
  <HideAction Visible="true" />

  <%--Cache the original size of the completion list the first time
    the animation is played and then set it to zero --%>
  <ScriptAction Script="// Cache the size and setup the initial size
                                var behavior = $find('AutoCompleteEx');
                                if (!behavior._height) {
                                    var target = behavior.get_completionList();
                                    behavior._height = target.offsetHeight - 2;
                                    target.style.height = '0px';
                                }" />
  <%-- Expand from 0px to the appropriate size while fading in --%>
  <Parallel Duration=".4">
  <FadeIn />
  <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValue="0" 
    EndValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx')._height" />
  </Parallel>
  </Sequence>
  </OnShow>
  <OnHide>
  <%-- Collapse down to 0px and fade out --%>
  <Parallel Duration=".4">
  <FadeOut />
  <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValueScript=
    "$find('AutoCompleteEx')._height" EndValue="0" />
  </Parallel>
  </OnHide>
  </Animations>
  </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" AutoCompleteType="FirstName" placeholder="Type First Name Here" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

And the AutoComplete.asmx.cs file

```
// (c) Copyright Microsoft Corporation.
// This source is subject to the Microsoft Public License.
// See http://www.microsoft.com/opensource/licenses.mspx#Ms-PL.
// All other rights reserved.
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

///<summary>
/// Summary description for AutoComplete
///</summary>

[WebService(Namespace = "localhost")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, 
// uncomment the following line.
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AutoComplete : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public AutoComplete()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components
        //InitializeComponent();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        //ADO.Net
        MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Database=bvshree;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=axcva4@@@3");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //Compare String From Textbox(prefixText) AND String From 
        //Column in DataBase(CompanyName)
        //If String from DataBase is equal to String from TextBox(prefixText) 
        //then add it to return ItemList
        //-----I defined a parameter instead of passing value directly to 
        //prevent SQL injection--------//
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from family_header Where Self_Name like @myParameter";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myParameter", "%" + prefixText + "%");

            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);


            cn.Close();

        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        //Then return List of string(txtItems) as result
        List<string> txtItems = new List<string>();
        String dbValues;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            //String From DataBase(dbValues)
            dbValues = row["Self_Name"].ToString();
            dbValues = dbValues.ToLower();
            txtItems.Add(dbValues);
        }

        return txtItems.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer this please someone need it urgently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this question again after long time, since none posted any reply I thought I should myself reply to it.
The Problem was with the styling of the code the opacity of the list being generated was set to zero and was not changing as expected. So I just removed to animation from it to get the solution. :)